# why anglaurjs doesn't set select model when ajax complete?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web

this is my html:

```
<select ng-model="currentProv" ng-options="p.N_PROVID as p.S_PROVNAME for p in tempProv" name="location_p" id="location_p" ng-change="getCity()">
```

and the select model is currentProv...
when the ajax request succeed,I will set the currentProv,code blow:

```
bizService
        .getProv()
        .success(function (data) {
            if(data.length) {
                $scope.tempProv = data;                 

                // $scope.currentProv = $scope.model.bizProvince;
                $rootScope.$broadcast('httpend');
            }
        })
```

this is the getProv service which get all the options,

and the global-page-model is getting from ajax too:

```
bizService
        .getData()
        .success(function (data) {
            if(data) {
                $scope.model = data;

                // console.log(data);
            }
            else {
                $scope.model = model;
            }
        });
```

which is : getGlobalModel->bind $scope.model and getProv ..bind $scope.model.currentProv...
but it doesn't work..what the problem?  thank you!

Comment: Can you setup a fiddle showing the issue?

Comment: sorry，diffcult to move it on jsfiddler，maybe i know the reason:options haven't render yet,I set the select model ,but how to solve it?use $timer?

Comment: You might be having scope problems.  tempProv may not be on the scope you thing it is

Comment: how can i know it on the scope or not？ you see I have already set $scope.tempProv

Comment: http://jsbin.com/newig/1/edit   this works fine..but why ajax failed?

Comment: and If I change " $scope.currentProv = $scope.model.bizProvince;" to "$scope.currentProv = 10"or other values,It works...but I have debug that..$scope.model.bizProvince has the value..